# FosElasticBundle not Analyzedfield

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have elastic search 2.2.1 and "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "~3.0",

I need add not analyzed for field in index I add in config to filed skill "fields" and "index: not_analyzed", but after

```
app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset --index=directory --type=skill
```

In mapping still have

```
"skill": {
  "properties": {
    "skill": {
      "type": "string"
    },
```

this my config:

```
    directory:
        finder: ~
        types:
                skill:
                 mappings:
                      id:
                         type: integer
                      skill:
                         type: integer
                         fields:
                            raw:
                                type: integer
                                index: not_analyzed
```

Mybe need update FosElasticBundle? what I'am doing wrong, any ideas, help

Answer (score 0):

Try to change "index" to true instead of "not_analyzed"

```
    directory:
    finder: ~
    types:
            skill:
             mappings:
                  id:
                     type: integer
                  skill:
                     type: integer
                     fields:
                        raw:
                            type: integer
                            index: true
```